# Browsers, CTRL-W for moving forward in weighed down position

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, keyboard

If You want to create a game.

And let your users use w-a-s-d as directions, why isn't  it possible to CTRL-w be assigned then. every key is assignable except CTRL-W ? so you can't use w-a-s-d in the game or CTRL cannot be crawl.

Comment: `CTRL+W` or `CMD+W` is already for closing the tab in chrome.

Comment: ALT-F4 is for closing the window, event.preventDefault  on ALT-F4 works, event.preventDefault on CTRL-W doesn't work.

Comment: `ALT+F4` is for all windows in Microsoft Windows, and `CTRL+W` is chrome specific though, this maybe the reason.